# Is it OK to put a JS fetch() request in a for() loop?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I need the JS on a weather station website to fetch the value of each sensor (4 times total) and then update the corresponding HTML elements.

On the server side, the URL `/reading?name=...&r=...` returns the reading "r" (eg. temperature) of sensor "name".

What I have right now is this:

```
function updateReadings() {
    secondsSinceLastUpdate = secondsSinceLastUpdate++;

    fetch('reading?name=bme280&r=1')
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( response => {
        //console.log(response);
        document.getElementById("bme280-1-rt1").innerHTML = response;
        secondsSinceLastUpdate = 0;
    } );


    fetch('reading?name=bme280&r=2')
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( response => {
        //console.log(response);
        document.getElementById("bme280-1-rt2").innerHTML = response;
        secondsSinceLastUpdate = 0;
    } );


    fetch('reading?name=bme280&r=3')
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( response => {
        //console.log(response);
        document.getElementById("bme280-1-rt3").innerHTML = response;
        secondsSinceLastUpdate = 0;
    } );


    fetch('reading?name=ds18b20-1&r=1')
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( response => {
        //console.log(response);
        document.getElementById('ds18b20-1-rt1').innerHTML = response;
        secondsSinceLastUpdate = 0;
    } );
}

setInterval(updateReading, 1000); // to update the readings every second
```

I want to somehow put all of these fetches into one construction (like a for() loop?), so I don't have to rewrite the code four times for every modification. I am not sure if it's a good idea to just shove it in a for() loop, but that's the first solution which comes to my mind.

I do not want to change anything on the server side: it must have individual URLs for every reading (I can not have a single fetch() for all readings at once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you do the loop and add them to a promise array and then use promise all to wait for all of them to resolve?

```
function updateReadings() {
    secondsSinceLastUpdate = secondsSinceLastUpdate++;

    const sensors = [
        { name: 'bme280', r: 1 },
        { name: 'bme280', r: 2 },
        { name: 'bme280', r: 3 },
        { name: 'ds18b20-1', r: 1 }
    ];

    const promises = [];
    for (const sensor of sensors) {
        const { name, r } = sensor;
        promises.push(fetch(`reading?name=${name}&r=${r}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                document.getElementById(`${name}-${r}-rt1`).innerHTML = response;
            }));
    }

    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(() => {
            secondsSinceLastUpdate = 0;
        });
}
```